# String Split & Search VB.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, string

Need to take a string in vb and split it. Also need to look through the two returned values and return the value which contains "domain1.com". Pipelines are the delimiter.

```
txtEmailFrom.Text = "john@huno.com|james@domain1.com"
Dim brokened() As String
brokened = Split(txtEmailFrom.Text, "|")
```

Dont know where to go from here...

Comment: you might want to look at this page, it shows you the many different ways you can split, search and parse strings in VB.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzcd8ze0%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtEmailFrom.Text = "john@huno.com|james@domain1.com"
Dim brokened() As String
dim email as string
dim emailSplit() as string
brokened = Split(txtEmailFrom.Text, "|")

for email in brokened
   emailSplit = Split(email, "|")
   if emailSplit(1) = "domain1.com" then
      Console.WriteLine(email)
   end if
next
```

I am writing this without IDE & this could be VB6 style.
Hopefully, it should give you an idea of converting to VB.net

EDIT: Ofcourse, it will be better to add checks for array bounds before this line `if emailSplit(1) = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each email In brokened
    If email.Contains("domain1.com") Then
        Return email
    End If
Next
```

Comment: There's a time and place for LINQ and I'd say that this is not one of them, a good old FOR loop like you have works best here and can be more easily read by everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use LINQ

```
 txtEmailFrom.Text = "john@huno.com|james@domain1.com"
 Dim result = txtEmailFrom.Text.Split(CChar("|")) _
              .Where(Function(d) d.Contains("domain1.com")).FirstOrDefault
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim brokened() As String = txtEmailFrom.Text.Split("|"c)

Dim returnValue as String 

For each item as String in brokened
  If item.Contains("domain1.com") Then
    returnValue = item
  End If 
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

(I got interrupted writing my answer, so I'm determined to finish!)

You can try this:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim email As String = "john@huno.com|james@domain1.com"

        Dim brokened() As String
        brokened = Split(email, "|")

        Dim k As List(Of String) = (From j As String In brokened _
                                    Where j.Contains("domain1.com") _
                                    Select j).ToList()

        For Each u As String In k
            Console.WriteLine(u)
        Next


    End Sub

End Module
```

Hope this helps.
Jas.

Comment: using firstOrDefault will not return an array or ienumeration

Comment: @Fredou - Your right, I had mis-understood the requirements. Have changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the splited email in a list and use the list.FindAll method to find all domain1.com

I'm going to write this in c#, i'm more familiar with it, but it should be the same for vb.net

```
List<string> emails = new List<string>();
emails.AddRange(txtEmailFrom.Text.Split("|".ToCharArray()));

emails.FindAll(s=> {return s.Contains("domain1.com");} );
```

something like that ... writing witout IDE

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim test As String = "john@huno.com|james@domain1.com"
Dim brokend() As String
brokend = test.Split(New String() {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.None)

For Each email As String In brokend
    If email.EndsWith("domain1.com") Then
        Return email;
    End If
Next
```