# How to copy separate words from a string into an array in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net

I am looking for a way to copy words from a string into an array using vb.net. I have looked at the various string manipulation options (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3s99sd8.aspx) although I cannot figure out how to copy a word from within a string by either deleting the current word or moving onto the next word and adding each word separately into an array.

E.g.

```
Dim Text as String = "The quick brown fox"
Dim TextArray() as String
```

Required output:

```
TextArray(0) = "The"
TextArray(1) = "quick"
TextArray(3) = "brown"
TextArray(4) = "fox"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Split & Search VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157290/string-split-search-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim results() As String = Split(input, " ")
```

Comment: I thought it would be something straightforward. Thank you for your prompt response.